# update matplotlib with patches

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

I have searched everywhere, but nothing seems to be working for me. My use case is very simple: I have a Robot that has a position and orientation. I want to plot this position and orientation on a graph. But, I want the robot to be able to move, so every time step T (lets let T = 1 second), I want the graph to update with the next robot position.

The way I am implementing my code, I generate an array of patches, one for each wheel and one for the body of the robot. Then, i simply want those three patches to be displayed to the graph. I can initialize the patches, but when I attempt to redraw them, I can't get the graph to redraw itself.

I know this is probably a question that has been answered, but I can't find any solution that works for my specific code. Please help!

```
def drawInitialize(self):

    #show the board itself
    x_lims = (0, self.width)
    y_lims = (0, self.length)
    self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, self.width+1, int(self.width/5)))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, self.length+1, int(self.length/5)))
    plt.xlim(x_lims)
    plt.ylim(y_lims)

    #print the robot (this works!)
    robotPatch = self.getRobotPatch()
    for i in range(len(robotPatch)):
        self.ax.add_patch(robotPatch[i])
        #self.ax.add_artist(robotPatch[i])
    plt.show()

def draw(self):
    self.ax.clear()
    robotPatch = self.getRobotPatch()
    for i in range(len(robotPatch)):
        self.ax.add_patch(robotPatch[i])
    plt.show() #THIS DOESNT WORK!!

#initialize the board, (this calls drawInitialize)
gb = GameBoard(500,750, Robot(300,450,1, wheel_radius=20, axel_length=85.0))

#this should rotate the robot and redraw it
for i in range(5):
    gb.draw() # this SHOULD redraw the robot! but nothing happens
    gb.robot.theta = gb.robot.theta + math.pi/2
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: iirc, you want something like `pyplot.draw` instead of `pyplot.show` -- [these examples](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.draw.html) may give you some inspiration

Comment: Turned out the reason nothing was working was because i was using inline instead of automatic after all. And I didn't realize that i had to restart the kernel to change to automatic. My code should work with changing Spyder's graphics config to automatic